# double quotes are coming in the file

Tags: shell, awk

I am facing a problem using awk. Actually I have two types of files. Below is the contain of file.

File1

```
x|y|z|a|b|c
x|y|z|a|b|c
x|y|z|a|b|c
```

File2

```
"x"|"y"|"z"|"a"|"b"|"c"
"x"|"y"|"z"|"a"|"b"|"c"
"x"|"y"|"z"|"a"|"b"|"c"
```

I have to search some value from second column by using awk. but the problem is that file1 has records without quotes whereas file2 has records with double quotes. I need to create a single logic to search the value from the second column.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What about deleting the `"` in file2? `tr -d '"' < file2` can make it.

Comment: We can't delete the quotes as there are some other logic are in the script

Comment: what do you mean "search"? search `y` in both files? or what?

Comment: Yes... Search Y in the both files but only in second column

Comment: You mean just search for `y` or also print `my`, `bye` because it has `y` in it?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed there is no need to clean the file. To look for value `y` in both files you can do the following:

```
$ awk -F"|" '$2~/y/' file1 file2
x|y|z|a|b|c
x|y|z|a|b|c
x|y|z|a|b|c
"x"|"y"|"z"|"a"|"b"|"c"
"x"|"y"|"z"|"a"|"b"|"c"
"x"|"y"|"z"|"a"|"b"|"c"
```

With a more complicated input:

```
$ cat file1
x|y|z|a|b|c
x|T|z|a|b|c
x|aa|y|a|b|c
$ cat file2
"x"|"y"|"z"|"a"|"b"|"c"
"x"|"22"|"z"|"a"|"b"|"c"
"x"|"t"|"y"|"a"|"b"|"c"
```

We get:

```
$ awk -F"|" '$2~/y/' file1 file2
x|y|z|a|b|c
"x"|"y"|"z"|"a"|"b"|"c"
```

Answer (score 1):

I wish you had posted some sample input (not just the format with x/y placeholders but actual data) and expected output so we could test our solutions but this SHOULD do what you want:

```
awk -F'"?[|]"?' '$2 == whatever' file
```

Replace "whatever" with whatever you're looking for, and replace == with ~ if you want an RE comparison rather than exact comparison.

If you had to be able to look in the first and last fields too, then there's various solutions and the "best" one would be determined by your real data but here's one approach if you have no undesirable RE metacharacters in "whatever":

```
awk -F'"?[|]"?' ' $1 ~ "^\"?" whatever    "$"' file
awk -F'"?[|]"?' '$NF ~ "^"    whatever "\"?$"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the quotes out with `sed 's/\"//g'` and pipe them to awk with `|`

```
$ sed 's/\"//g' file2
x|y|z|a|b|c
x|y|z|a|b|c
x|y|z|a|b|c
```

Your end result would be something like

```
$ sed 's/\"//g' file2 | awk <magic goes here...>
```

Comment: That would change the file format for `"|"`-separated files to `|`-separated which is probably undesirable. If that was OK, there's a trivial solution entirely within awk just by setting OFS="|" and then assigning $1=$1 so the sed would be not be useful either way.